# Pular linha no XML com Python

Tags: python, xml, script

Olá! Estou criando um programa em Python onde a saída do programa será um script em XML na linguagem ABAP (para uma transport especifica do SAP), porém quando exporto a saída para XML ele não exporta identada, ou seja, tudo na mesma linha.

Como sai:

```
<lista><usuario><user name="user">admin</user><senha name="senha">123456</senha><nome name="nome">Fulano de Tal</nome></usuario></lista>
```

Como quero que saia:

```
<lista>
   <usuario>
       <user name="user">admin</user>
       <senha name="senha">123456</senha>
       <nome name="nome">Fulano de Tal</nome>
   </usuario>
</lista>
```

O código que estou usando:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
class XML(object):
 def __init__(self, usuario, senha, nome):
    self.usuario = usuario
    self.senha = senha
    self.nome = nome

 def gerar_xml(self):    
    lista = ET.Element("lista")
    no_usuario = ET.SubElement(lista, "usuario")
    ET.SubElement(no_usuario, "user", name="user").text = self.usuario
    ET.SubElement(no_usuario, "senha", name="senha").text = self.senha
    ET.SubElement(no_usuario, "nome", name="nome").text = self.nome                
    arquivo = ET.ElementTree(lista)
    arquivo.write("meu_xml.xml")

def main():
  xml = XML("admin", "123456", "Fulano de Tal")
  xml.gerar_xml()    

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teoricamente você não precisa acrescentar estes espaços. O formato XML é feito para ser consumido por outros programas e não por humanos, portanto, não precisa dessas quebras de linha e indentações. O programa que vai consumir esse XML não vai reclamar, pois o XML é válido dessa forma que está. Além disso, acrescentar essas indentações vai aumentar o tamanho do seu arquivo desnecessariamente.

Por esses motivos, o módulo `xml.etree` do python não tem suporte a essa funcionalidade. Se ainda assim quiser "embelezar" o seu XML, terá que usar uma biblioteca alternativa para lidar com ele. Eu sugiro a excelente biblioteca `lxml.etree`, pois ela possui uma API bastante parecida com a do `xml.etree`, sendo que provavelmente você não precisará reescrever nada.

Usando o `lxml`, fica assim:

```
arquivo.write("meu_xml.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: É pq no caso, o usuário tera q pegar o conteúdo desse XML gerado e adicionar no script Final manualmente. E no script final está identado, então para não haver confusão optei por deixar dessa forma também. Usei a API do LXML com o comando pretty_print e funcionou certinho! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se você der uma olhada [nessa pergunta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/749796/1284458) conhecerá muitas respostas interessantes. Vou deixar aqui um breve resumo de algumas respostas e uma função em python para indentar seu XML caso não seja possível usar outra biblioteca:

---

### Usando `xml.dom.minidom`

```
import xml.dom.minidom

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(xml_fname) # or xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_string)
pretty_xml_as_string = dom.toprettyxml()
```

---

### Usando `lxml`

Como o @nosklo já mencionou na resposta dele:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

x = etree.parse("filename")
print etree.tostring(x, pretty_print=True)
```

---

### Alterando os nodos de texto do seu XML

Uma das opções é usar uma [função para alterar os nodos de texto do seu XML](https://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint) para fazer a indentação do arquivo. Aconselho a modificar o XML apenas para visualização.

```
def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level * "  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for elem in elem:
            indent(elem, level + 1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i
```

<sup>Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-414800-6333)</sup>